# Unable to verify ID for Google Developer account

Tags: google-play-console, google-developers-console

There is not possible to verify ID during enrolling to Google Developer Account. I got rejects on all new partner's accounts. Moreover, old accounts that have successfully passed verification earlier when updating the application also receive a message
`We couldn't verify your ID, so you won't be able to publish apps on Google Play from this account.`

I received all these errors in the last 5 days, before that there were no problems with ID's verification.

Comment: any update @Andrey?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question, not a programming question. Contact Google support directly for issues related to your account. We have no access to that account in order to help troubleshoot or resolve the problem. For more information, see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/62576)